# how do I send the values stored in a cookie while executing a load test in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, cookies, load-testing

I want to carry out a load test on my application using Visual Studio 2010 Team Suite but I store certain login details in the cookie. When i tried doing a load test, the variables stored in the cookie do not get retrieved and the test is unable to even enter into the application. How can I go about retrieving these variables from the cookie?
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify and add more detail. What do you mean by _"I store certain login details in the cookie"_? How do you store the data? Are you referring to your application or your test code? What do you mean by _"the variables stored in the cookie do not get retrieved"_? Visual Studio handles cookies automatically, so please elaborate on exactly what you mean. Are you using an Initialize test that performs the login?

Answer (score -2):

If you're willing to drop the "using Visual Studio 2010" requirement and decide to use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for load testing (like many of us) you'll have plenty of support for handling cookies.